# How to trigger a delegate method after a certain period of time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer, nsnotification

I'm using a class which downloads a file asynchronously .. works a bit like this

```
// in AViewController.m
DataGetter *blueFile = [[DataGetter alloc] init];
blueFile.delegate = self;
[blueFile getData:@"http://example.com/blue-file"];
```

It has a delegate method which does stuff to the file once downloaded

```
- (void) dataGetterFinished:(DataGetter *)dataGetter
{
// code
}
```

This works OK in ideal conditions, but as we're dealing with a mobile device, connections are not always reliable. The connection might break off half way thru, or it might be unusably slow.

So I'm wondering how I would set up a delegate method which triggers after, say, 10 seconds, which then displays an error and stops the operation. Would I have to use NSTimer, or NSNotification , or some combination?

Comment: have you thought about using a library like http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ ? there you can set timeouts, auto retrys, using cached objects when network fails and stuff like that.

Comment: too far down the road on this particular app, but i'l probably use the all-seeing-i classes in future apps

Comment: A time-out of 10 seconds is not something that is recommended for a mobile device. It can take longer just to establish connectivity over cellular network. You should instead trust the sane time-outs provided by the URL Loading System classes, such as `NSURLConnection`.

Answer (score 1):

Quinn "The Eskimo!" from Apple did a two talks on network programming for iPhone at WWDC 2010. It's session 207 and 208, you can download them here: http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/

The simple recepie for network success is:

1. Use `NSURLConnection` asynchronously.
2. Do **not** set a manual time-out using timers or any other means, the defaults are sane.
3. Instead be prepared to handle for a `connection:didFailWithError:`, that will be sent for time-outs.
4. If needed you can manually cancel a connection using `-[NSURLConnection cancel]`, in response to user action for example.